# Can we get location validation when scan a gps qr code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, gps

i have a question. I make a GenerateQR make by 2 input ( 2 data in the input ). I can use 1 input to make QRgenerate but with 2 input it not working.
Here's my code:

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper"),
qrInput1 = wrapper.querySelector(".form input1"),
qrInput2 = wrapper.querySelector(".form input2"),
generateBtn = wrapper.querySelector(".form button"),
qrImg = wrapper.querySelector(".qr-code img");
let preValue;
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let qrValue1 = qrInput1.value.trim();
    let qrValue2 = qrInput2.value.trim();
    if(!qrValue1 && qrInput2 || preValue === qrValue1 && preValue === qrValue2) return;
    preValue1 = qrValue1;
    preValue2 = qrValue2;
    generateBtn.innerText = "Generating QR Code...";
    qrImg.src = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=${qrValue}`;
    qrImg.addEventListener("load", () => {
        wrapper.classList.add("active");
        generateBtn.innerText = "Generate QR Code";
    });
});
qrInput1.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    if(!qrInput1.value.trim()) {
        wrapper.classList.remove("active");
        preValue1 = "";
    }
});
qrInput2.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    if(!qrInput2.value.trim()) {
        wrapper.classList.remove("active");
        preValue2 = "";
    }
});
```

about JS file, i using qrInput1 and qrInput2 but it seems not working after all. so anyone know the solution for my problem

Comment: Look at your variable names. you have declared them as qrValue1 and qrValue2, but image source you have just used 'qrValue'
qrImg.src = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=${qrValue}`;

Comment: Can you define what you want to happen when you provide two inputs? Two separate QR codes, or the two inputs joined together in the same QR code? It would be good to get some more context of what you're trying to do.